# How to quantify the relationship between known group assignment and cluster assignment

Tags: r, correlation, clustering, chi-squared-test

Consider this data frame:

```r
> dput(data)
structure(list(Location = structure(1:18, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
"p", "q", "r"), class = "factor"), C1 = c(7L, NA, 3L, 7L, NA, 
NA, 2L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C2 = c(NA, 
8L, 1L, 1L, NA, 9L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L), C3 = c(3L, 1L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 7L, NA, NA), C4 = c(NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 
8L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 15L, NA), C5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 8L, NA, 2L, NA, 4L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

We sampled multiple individuals from `Location`s `a:r`. We measured some arbitrary variable, and used an unsupervised approach to cluster observations based on that variable. `data` above is the contingency table showing how many individuals were assigned to each cluster `C1:C5`. We want to know if there is a significant relationship between `Location` and cluster assignment. We cant use a Chi-Square test for this many groups, so what would be an appropriate way to test for this?